# How to recieve data of a group by sqlite query in iOS ?

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite

I want to get data of my group by query and load them into textfields.
here is my table
integer ID
Name text
Duration Real
Time Real
there are few names in in Name column
I tried calling  method for each name , but it caused insert failure.

I want receive this query and load the result on specific Label: i dont know how can get the response

```
SELECT  Name,SUM (time) FROM  cost GROUP BY Name;
```

there  is my current code

```
 NSString *docsDir;
NSArray *dirPaths;

 double totaltime = 1.0;

// Get the documents directory
dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
docsDir = dirPaths[0];

// Build the path to the database file
databasePath = [[NSString alloc]
                initWithString: [docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:
                                 @"Database.db"]];


NSString *queryString=@"SELECT SUM(DURATION) AS TOTAL FROM RECORDS";
sqlite3_stmt    *statement;

if(sqlite3_open([databasePath UTF8String], &myDatabase) == SQLITE_OK) {

    if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(myDatabase, [queryString UTF8String], -1, &statement, nil) == SQLITE_OK){
        while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW) {
             totaltime =  sqlite3_column_double(statement, 0);
            NSLog(@"The sum is  %f ", totaltime);
        }
    }
}
integer_t intotal=totaltime;
NSString* total=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d min",intotal];
totaltimefield.text=total;
```

Comment: Not a solution to your problem, I know, but have you any reason not to use CoreData? It saves you a lot of pain when dealing with SQLite databases and it's integration facilitates the reuse of your data as your project grows.

Comment: What's the question? A "group by "column can be accessed the same way as any other column.

Comment: @Paul I find that "group by" expressions are something that's often easier in SQL than Core Data.

Comment: I know its better to use core data,  But it has long story. its part of my final engineering project.and college forced me to use relational  database. Honestly after I got my mark, I should rebuild  the project with CoreData.

Comment: @StephenDarlington And I don't like writing lots of verbose SQL boilerplate code when CoreData provides me with a object-oriented API. :) I see your point, but he wouldn't be the first one to ask some SQLite question without knowing about the existence of CoreData.

Comment: @StephenDarlington  I dont know how to get  data.  I mean i dont know hot to get statement result into  textfield. because there are two colums.one for name and one for sum

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is all covered pretty [nicely in the documentation](http://sqlite.org/c3ref/column_blob.html), but, in short, once you update your SQL to have two columns:

```
const unsigned char* name = sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0);
double totaltime =  sqlite3_column_double(statement, 1);
NSLog(@"The sum for %s is  %f ", name, totaltime);
```

The second parameter int the `sqlite3_column_x` functions is the column number.

Comment: thank you it solved first part, then there are 10 rows. I should receive their data and copy the totaltime value in specific labels.What do you suggest?creating a class for the result and adding its objects to a nsmutablearray then using a switch case?

Comment: Why not a dictionary mapping from name to the total time?

Comment: yeah its a better idea , i try using NSdictionar

Comment: I tied to do that, I wrote below code, but I think i did something wrong.

Comment: Use an `NSMutableDictionary`. Add stuff to it using `setObject:forKey`.